# Android Studio 2022.3.1 (Mac Intel) cannot create Flutter projects

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-plugin

With the upgrade to version 2022.3.1 (Giraffe), my Android Studio on Mac Intel stopped producing Flutter projects. I tried to purge Android Studio completely and to reinstall - same result. Both Flutter and Dart plugins are installed. Flutter is installed (3.10.6) and `flutter doctor` gives it a pass with one strange thing: for Android Studio plugins (which *are* installed), it says:

```
Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
```

Creating projects via `flutter create` works as expected.

The symptoms are as follows:

- *Projects* section has a new button: *"New Flutter Project"*
- Clicking this button however brings a generic project wizard, not a Flutter one. Continuing with the wizard generates a generic Java (or Kotlin) "Hello World" project (see below):

[image: New Flutter project wizard]

Am I missing something? Or is it something others noticed as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select Flutter as shown in the below picture then select the SDK path where you put it then click on Next it'll create a flutter project for you.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, that was apparently the new workflow. Thank you!

Comment: omg lol wow.  I just reinstalled MacOS and my entire development environment because i thought this was an unsolvable configuration bug.